# Is there a faster way of moving rows of data between SQL Server databases than using CTE's?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, archive

I use the following query on SQL Server 2012 Express to move data that is older than 4 days old out of one [primary] database and into another [secondary database] for archiving purposes. The only issue is that this takes the database offline as it is usually moving about 500k rows of data, and that figure is climbing with more data points being added to the database. The result is that my web based app is not able to access the database for (in most cases) about 2 hours, and this stalls a lot of other processes, as well as the app.

```
DECLARE @4daysago datetime
SELECT @4daysago = DATEADD(d, -4, GetDate());

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [activetrackarchivedb].dbo.[Data Import] ON;

--Transfer from current (production) DB to Archive DB
WITH CTE as (
    SELECT TOP 1000000 *
    FROM [activetrackdb].dbo.[Data Import] 
    WHERE [activetrackdb].dbo.[Data Import].[Receive Date] < @7daysago
    ORDER BY [Receive Date] ASC)
DELETE CTE
  OUTPUT DELETED.id, 
  DELETED.[Company id], 
  DELETED.[Site id],
  DELETED.[Site name],
  DELETED.[Receive date],
  DELETED.[Detect date],
  INTO  [activetrackarchivedb].dbo.[Data Import] 
  (id, 
  [Company id], 
  [Site id],
  [Site name],
  [Receive date],
  [Detect date]);
```

Is there a better method I could use to 'transfer' these rows? Even if the new method was slower, if it could at least still allow access to the database. This one took me a week to implement (I'm a novice) and involved the StackOverflow community's help. It's been great up until now, but as amount of data has increased, its become a very cumbersome process.

This is not for backup purposes either. The database the rows are transferred to simply have a higher capacity and the archived data is still used in the production environment (it just makes the primary database more maintainable and responsive when combined with other maintenance and indexing scripts)

Comment: If you don't have an index for Receive Date you could also test if creating it makes it faster. Especially if you're doing it several times in smaller batches having an index should help.

Comment: Even though Stack Overflow has many members with solid SQL Server programming skills, this might be more of an DBA problem and I would post the question on [dba.se] instead as that community is more aimed at administration issues (or so I believe).

Comment: Why are you using a CTE? Are you trying to batch this somehow?

Comment: Thanks to bot of you for your responses. I do already have an index on that coloumn, and it does help, but it is still slow... I will repost on the Database Administrators Excahnge- good point. Will keep both up until I resolve this though :)

Comment: No particular reason RE CTE, what would be better?

Comment: why do you sort in your cte? i understood, you repeat that statement until no record gets selected

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS (2008) and many other places SQL Server defaults to a row number size of 10000. You may want to experiment with the size of rows you are doing at a time but I suspect that a smaller size may end up executing a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run something like this (assuming that the tables have the same fields):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [activetrackarchivedb].dbo.[Data Import] ON;

DELETE FROM [activetrackdb].dbo.[Data Import]
OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO  [activetrackarchivedb].dbo.[Data Import] 
WHERE [activetrackdb].dbo.[Data Import].[Receive Date] < DATEADD(DAY,-4,GETDATE())
```

I don't see why that would take much longer than a minute, and probably a lot less than that.  500k rows isn't really that many for SQL Server to handle.  A similar statement with that number of rows takes about 5 seconds to complete on my laptop.

Comment: I dont know why I got to where I did, so you may well be right. I have tried but I get the following error: Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'activetrackarchivedb.dbo.Data Import' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: Oh yeah, you still need that statement in your query if you're going to be inserting data into the primary key on the destination table.  I updated my code example.

Comment: Now getting this but my coloumns are identical, datetimes and varchars?  'Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, the CTE seems unnecessary.  You can do it with a much simpler query.

```
DELETE FROM [activetrackdb].dbo.[Data Import]
  OUTPUT 
      DELETED.id, 
      DELETED.[Company id], 
      DELETED.[Site id],
      DELETED.[Site name],
      DELETED.[Receive date],
      DELETED.[Detect date]
  INTO  [activetrackarchivedb].dbo.[Data Import] 
      (id, 
       [Company id], 
       [Site id],
       [Site name],
       [Receive date],
       [Detect date]) 
WHERE [Receive Date] < @7daysago
```

Comment: would this speed it up?

Comment: @Chen_Dogg Possibly.  Not having to create a CTE could help.  It will depend a lot on the actual execution plans, indexes, etc.  The only way to really know would be to try.  (My guess is it should, but there are too many factors to say for certain.)